# App Engine + objectify: the filter class not found

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I've added objectify to my project (confirmed it's working properly), but I also tried adding the filter mapping in web.xml as is recommended [here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Setup), but I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:202)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:248)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
Oct 25, 2012 10:45:33 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed ObjectifyFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter
Oct 25, 2012 10:45:33 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@1acaf0ed{/,C:\Users\mshaham\eclipse\test2510\war}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:202)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:248)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
```

I'm using the latest objectify with GAE 1.7.2 on eclipse

Comment: where did you put objectify jar ? it must be in war/WEB-INF/lib for the servlet container to find it;

Comment: @koma yup, that's where it is. I can confirm eclipse *does* recognize other classes of the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using the Objectify3 jar but following the Objectify4 documentation.  I suggest grabbing the latest Objectify4 jar from the maven repository (official release coming soon).  If you are hesitant, the Objectify3 docs are in the Wiki sidebar.

Comment: That was ridiculously confusing and totally should have been clear in the docs! and thank you...

Comment: How can I make it more clear?  The links to the docs in the wiki clearly say "User's Guide (Objectify v4)" and "Objectify v3 (obsolete)".